# MapReduce Python, Can't seem to pipe criteria to text file

Tags: python, mapreduce

First of all, I'm very new to MapReduce (just this week in fact) and doing it as part of a course I'm currently on so forgive me if I am making basic errors.

I have tried searching for a answer to my problem but I'm finding anything of relevance.

I have a text file of lines where the data is simple, for example:

```
Reg1, Yes
Reg2, No
Reg3, Yes
Reg4, Yes
Reg5, Yes
Reg6, Yes
Reg7, Yes
Reg8, No
Reg9, Yes
Reg10, Yes
Reg11, Yes
Reg12, Yes
Reg13, Yes
Reg14, No
Reg15, Yes
```

The first thing I wanted to do is count the yes and no - this part is working fine but using a second model to pipe the 'reg' words to a text file if it is a 'No'. I have read somewhere it is better to look at the lines rather than words in this situation, which makes sense.

Below is my attempt at gaining a mapper that does this:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:

line = line.strip()

lines = line.split()

for line in lines:
    if 'Yes' in line:
        sys.stdout.write('%s\t%s\n' % (line,1))

    else:
        sys.stderr.write('%s\t%s\n' % (line,1))

    print('%s\t%s' % (line, 1))
```

but the resulting output is:

```
Reg1,   1
Reg2,   1
No  1
Reg3,   1
Reg4,   1
Reg5,   1
Reg6,   1
Reg7,   1
Reg8,   1
No  1
Reg9,   1
Reg10,  1
Reg11,  1
Reg12,  1
Reg13,  1
Reg14,  1
No  1
Reg15,  1
```

whereas I just want my output to be:

```
Reg2, No
Reg8, No
Reg14, No
```

Can anyone please give a pointer on where I am going wrong? This bit of work is only for theoretical purposes that is why I am using Python (plus this is what the tutor demonstrated in)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sys.stderr.write('%s\t%s\n', % (line, 1))` will always replace the first `%s` with `line` and the second one with just the int `1`. Probably a good idea to start there with your output. Second thing you should do is verify that `line` actually contains the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to split the lines into words.
The `in` operator can identify a sub-string within a string.

and then you also don't need to do so much printing, eventually your code would be

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    if 'Yes' in line:
        # print(line) # we don't want to print the Yes lines
        pass
        # but if we want to leave the IF unchanged, then a pass instruction needs to fill it
    else:
        print(line)
        # if you want results to be pipe-able, comment line above, uncomment line below
        #sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: This worked prefect. Thanks very much.  When I look at it, makes perfect sense to just pass the line if yes is there. Thanks again.